# Recipe for Ruby 2.1 debugging on OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, debugging

I'm looking for a way to debug in ruby 2.1 on OSX.  Specifically:

- Ruby 2.1.0
- Rails (3.2.recent)
- OS X 10.9.1

I'm looking for a recipe that will let me stop at breakpoints, step, next, etc.  I've used the debugger gem in the past, ruby-debug, and also byebug.  I'm having trouble getting any of 'em to build.

Anyone have a recipe that works?  Thanks!

Comment: check out pry gem and https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug

Comment: Second `pry`. Best Ruby development tool bar none. See [here](http://pryrepl.org) for more on Pry.

Comment: Hmm.  I tried pry-plus and it failed.  Maybe if I scale it back...

Comment: @uDaY - just basic pry (with pry-nav) works like a charm - I should have known.  Make yours an answer instead of a comment if you want the credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with `pry` is a great option when you want to debug.

Checkout the vid tutorial http://pryrepl.org/screencasts.html which showcases some of the features of it.

I generally use these gems for debugging:

```
group :development do
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-nav'
  gem 'pry-rescue'
  gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
  gem 'pry-doc'
end
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can also checkout [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) which is a simple ruby debugger for versions >= 2.0.

Comment: I tried using byebug and could not get it to stop at a breakpoint under ruby 2.1 on os x.

Comment: I am running Ruby 2.1 on OSX with no problem.  You have the gem included?  Then you just drop "byebug" in your code and it looks just like the old debugger.  Are you breaking out of a test?

Comment: Seemed to slide right by the byebug breakpoint.  I won't be doing any more 2.1 work until this BigDecimal issue gets resolved: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9305